# Forge viewer hangs on loading spinner

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am running into an interesting problem when loading the Forge viewer on a mobile device. On a desktop browser I have no problems, but when I try to load the viewer on a mobile browser (tried Safari and Chrome) the viewer hangs for about 20 seconds on the loading spinner. The spinner itself even hangs, making me think something is blocking the whole UI thread. I did some digging and this always happens just before loading / while loading the toolbar. Some other clues, this app is running as a PWA following Petr Broz's disconnected workflows blog post, however the problem happens even when online. Viewer version is 7.*. Any idea what may be causing this?

UPDATE: Many tests later, I have concluded that the problem is present in any implementation of the Forge viewer on Vue when attempting to load large models on Safari. In addition to my own app I tried [the Forge Vuer](https://github.com/alvpickmans/forge-vuer) package and it has the same problem. The whole viewer hangs when loading the toolbar on Safari only. I have no clue why this occurs. Some weird interaction with the virtual DOM maybe?

Comment: Hi Jacob, blog post author reporting here :) That sounds really strange. I've no idea why the explode extension of all things would cause any lags... Let me see if I can reproduce the same issue on my end. Are there any specific repro steps? Or should I just use the sample app from the blog post?

Comment: Hi Petr. I sent an email to support with a link to my app. After unregistering the Explode extension entirely before it loads, I discovered that wasn't the problem. The viewer still hangs on mobile only right after the NavTools extension loads. The rest of the extensions load about 20 seconds later. Is there an event they may be waiting on that could be blocking the load?

Comment: That's good to know, thanks Jacob. Although I still can't think of anything that could be blocking the loading for this long...